# Type error in python/pygame - float instead of integer

Tags: python, pygame

I have a small program in python and pygame
but when I run my it I get this error:

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 25, in main
    board.draw(WIN)
  File "/home/ether/Desktop/checkersai/checker/board.py", line 42, in draw
    piece.draw(win)
  File "/home/ether/Desktop/checkersai/checker/piece.py", line 32, in draw
    pygame.draw.circle(win, GREY, (self.x, self.y), radius + self.OUTLINE)
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

and this is the function where the error is:

```
def draw(self, win):
        radius = SQUARE_SIZE//2 - self.PADDING
        pygame.draw.circle(win, GREY, (self.x, self.y), radius + self.OUTLINE)
        pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y), radius)
```

and these are the variables I use:

```
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800,800
ROWS, COLS = 8,8
SQUARE_SIZE = WIDTH/COLS
```

So I don't see how I get this error nor do I have any idea where I need to start looking for the error.

Here is the full code to my project
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/DHcRNT6948/

Comment: The operator you used in `SQUARE_SIZE = WIDTH/COLS` looks a bit different from what you used in `radius = SQUARE_SIZE//2 - self.PADDING`, doesn't it?

Comment: Something in this call is a float and must be cast to int: `pygame.draw.circle(win, GREY, (self.x, self.y), radius + self.OUTLINE)`

Comment: i dont understand what you mean

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 i know but i have nothing in my code that is a float or turns into a float. Its a checkers board

Comment: If Python says you've got a float, almost always, you've got a float.

Comment: You can always print out the values being passed in to see whether they are floats or not. I believe pygame 2 solves this issue by accepting floats as parameters. To import pygame 2 do `pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though you used the integer division operator (`//`) when setting `radius = SQUARE_SIZE//2 - self.PADDING`, it's returning a float; that operator would normally return an int, but it still returns a float if you're dividing a float. In your case, you're dividing a float, `SQUARE_SIZE`. It's a float because `SQUARE_SIZE = WIDTH/COLS` uses the regular division operator (`/`), which *always* returns a float.

To fix your issue, do something like this:

```
SQUARE_SIZE = WIDTH//COLS  # SQUARE_SIZE is an int now
```

However, a more mathematically accurate approach would be to work with floats, and round & convert to int only at the last moment:

```
radius = int(round((WIDTH/COLS) / 2.0 - self.PADDING))
```

Comment: even if use radius = SQUARE_SIZE/2 - self.PADDING  i get the same error

Comment: @yappytwan That's giving you the same result because as I explained in my answer, the regular division operator returns a float; it's not that line that is causing the error. It's the fact that `SQUARE_SIZE` is a float, which happened because of the line `SQUARE_SIZE = WIDTH/COLS`.